# React testint library jest regex

Tags: reactjs, regex, unit-testing, jestjs

I would like to test a regex with react testing library and jest.
This regex allows to remove 3 postal codes.

```
   export const addressFieldsConfigShippingOverrideCdc = {
   ...addressFieldsConfigShippingOverride,
    postalCode: {
    validationRegex: {
          GB: RegExp(
            /^(?!GY|JE|IM)[A-Z]{1,2}([0-9]{1,2}|[0-9][A-Z])[\s-]{0,1}[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i,
          ),
          IT: RegExp(/^(?!00120|47890|22061)[0-9]{5}$/),
        },
      },
    };
```

The 3 postal codes to remove are 00120 47890 and 22061.

```
I have created file test.jsx
    
    describe('stringMatching in arrayContaining', () => {
      const expected = [
        expect.not.stringMatching(/^00120/),
        expect.not.stringMatching(/^47890/),
        expect.not.stringMatching(/^22061/),
      ];
      it('matches even if received contains additional elements', () => {
        expect(['00120', '47890', '22061']).toEqual(
          expect.arrayContaining(expected),
        );
      });
```

I would like for my tests to see if my postal codes are excluded from the regex.
Thanks for all

Comment: You need word or numeric boundaries instead of anchors to match anywhere inside the string. Try with word boundaries first, replace each `^` and `$` with `\b` in your regexps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfectly clear what you want do to here.

If you want to test the regex only, you could do something like:

```
describe("regex", () => {
  const regexp = RegExp(/^(?!00120|47890|22061)[0-9]{5}$/);

  describe("regexp", () => {
    it("does not match 00120", () => {
      expect(regexp.test("00120")).toBe(false);
    });

    it("matches 38019", () => {
      expect(regexp.test("38019")).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```